# Programmatically Solve Recurrency equations in Closed form?

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$
\begin{cases}
V(k)=0 \text{ as } k < 1 \\
V(k+1) -V(k) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(V(k) - V(k-1) \right) \text{ as } k \in [1,9] \\
V(k+1) = V(k) \text{ as } k >9 
\end{cases}
$$

I have got

$$V(10) - V(9) = (\frac{1}{2} (V(9) - V(8))$$
so
$$1 = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) V(9) - \frac{1}{2} V(8)$$
and
$$V(9) = \frac{3}{2} V(8) - \frac{1}{2} V(7)$$
...
$$V(2) - V(1) = (\frac{1}{2} (V(1) - V(0))$$
so
$$V(2) = \frac{3}{2} V(1)$$

now I got

$$V(3) = \frac{7}{6} V(2)$$

```
n  | V
---------
0  | 0
1  | V(1)
2  | 3/2 *V(1)
3  | 7/4 *V(1)
4  | 15/8 *V(1)
5 ...
6
7
8
9  ..
10 | 1
```

without calculating this by hands like this, is there some easy way to programmatically do this?

Comment: Where you have 7/6 you probably mean 7/4

Comment: @Henry: thank you,fixed.

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67386/linear-homogeneous-difference-equation-with-constant-coefficients/67418#67418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $k$ must be an integer, are you looking for something similar to this?

- $V(0) = 0 \text{ for } k \lt 1$
- $V(k)=\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}} V(1) \text{ for } k \in [1,9]$
- $V(k) = \dfrac{511}{256} V(1) \text{ for } k \gt 9$

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence (below $k=10$) is $V(k+1)=\frac{3}{2}V(k)-\frac{1}{2}V(k-1)$.  The standard approach for linear homogeneous recurrences like this is to assume the solutions are of the form $ar^k$.  If you substitute that into your recurrence, the $a$'s divide out and you are left with $2r^2=3r-1$  Solving this gives $r=1,\frac{1}{2}$ so the general solution is $V(k)=a+b(\frac{1}{2})^k$ and you need two initial conditions to get $a$ and $b$.  In your case, you have $V(0)=0$ and we will let $V(1)=c$.  Then $a+b=0, a+\frac{b}{2}=c$, leading to $V(k)=2c(1-\frac{1}{2^{k}})$.  Then you need to impose the fact that nothing changes after $k=9$.  A discussion is at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) and there are texts on linear recurrence relations.