# Solving Linear Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following :
$$
Y'(t)=JY(t)+K(t)
$$
where $Y, J, K$ are matrices. The text book I have tells me the following for $J=J_3(\lambda)$:
$$\begin{align}
y'_1(t)&=\lambda y_1(t)+K_1(t)\\
y'_2(t)&=\lambda y_2(t)+(y_1(t)+K_2(t))\\
y'_3(t)&=\lambda y_3(t)+(y_2(t)+K_3(t)) 
\end{align}$$

If I have $$K(t)= \begin{pmatrix}
3\\
e^t-6\\
e^{-3t}-e^t+3
\end{pmatrix}$$

then am I correct in setting up the first equation as follows:
If $\lambda=-1$, $y'_1(t)=-y_1(t)+3$, then I could use the integrating factor of $e^t$ and solve to get:
$y_1$(t)=3+c$e^{-t}$

Is this correct so far?

Can someone please step me through getting $y_2(t)$?

Comment: Are you sure that your textbook wants you to solve the equations one by one but not with a Laplace transform?

Comment: and also J is for a possible Jordan block?

Comment: The solution to $Y'=AY+K(t)$, $Y(t_0)=Y_0$, where $A$ is a constant square matrix and $K$ is continuous, is $$e^{(t-t_0)A}\ Y_0+\int_{t_0}^te^{(t-x)A}\ K(x)\ dx.$$ Moreover, there is a closed formula for $e^{tA}$: see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/how-to-calculate-the-matrix-exponential-explicitly-for-a-matrix-which-isnt-diago/34139#34139) for instance.