# A basic doubt to compute exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

Given a matrix I want to evaluate $e^{A}$. The method suggested uses the taylor expansion. But, it is also written that the method works well if the largest and smallest eigen values are not well separated. why ?

Comment: see http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy: That's a little dubious :-).

Comment: @copper.hat: Why should this paper be dubious? Note that Cleve Moler has built the first version of Matlab.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: It was a joke. The original paper was titled something like "19 dubious ways to compute the exponential". I used to work with the old (free) Fortran version of Matlab which even had the rtfm command.

Comment: @copper.hat, I never read it, it is in one of the comments after my http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80324/sina-where-a-is-a-matrix/80332#80332  a little after the gerbils

Comment: @WillJagy: Funny! (Btw, I think the gerbils might find a Schur form to be preferable to the Jordan normal form from a numerical standpoint...)