# Is there a way to compute the exponential of a PDP-1 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

I am computing the exponential of a matrix via Taylor expansion to prove the end-result with induction.

For a matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is the diagonalized matrix, is there any kind of formula for adding their sums like in the instance of

$$I+PDP^{-1}+\frac{PD^{2}P^{-1}}{2!}+\frac{PD^{3}P^{-1}}{3!}...?$$

Comment: Factor it out as $P\left(I + D + \frac{D^2}{2!} + \frac{D^3}{3!} + \ldots\right)P^{-1}$. The stuff between parentheses consists of sums over the diagonal entries which are just the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$, and the entry-wise sum converges to a diagonal matrix with entries equal to $e^{\lambda_i}$. Of course you would first need to define a metric on the space of matrices, and show that limits commute with multiplication.

Comment: Of course, good observation. If you made that into an answer I would accept it.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/how-to-calculate-the-matrix-exponential-explicitly-for-a-matrix-which-isnt-diag?).