# Exponential of Jordan Form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let J be a single 4 x 4 Jordan block with lambda on the diagonal. Write the matrix e^Jt.

Would you help me about this? What should I do with e^Jt? I can find the exp(J) but are there any difference with 'Jt'?

my e^J form is {e^l,e,1,1},{1,e^l,e,1},{1,1,e^l,e},{1,1,1,e^l}
l=lambda

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: first work out the formula for the $n$th power of a Jordan block. Then expand the exponential as a power series.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, just replace $J$ in $\exp(J)$ by $Jt$! That is $\exp(Jt)=I+Jt+\frac{1}{2}(Jt)^2+\frac{1}{6}(Jt)^3+\ldots$

Comment: There is a closed formula for the exponential of a Jordan block. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204380/the-exponential-of-a-jordan-block) for an example with a $3\times 3$ Jordan block.